# Warning thrown: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8, php-7.2

While using `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",`

I get the following error:

```
    $user = App\User::find(314);
    dump(PHP_VERSION);
    dump(is_object($user));
    dump(is_array($user));
    dump(count($user));
    dd($user);
```

I get the following error `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

However when I silence the warning. We get the correct output `@dump(count($user));`

```
"7.2.19"
true
false
1
User {#821 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #guarded: array:5 [▶]

....
```

---

Note: **count() works when** the collection has more than 1.

```
    $users = App\User::find([12,13,14,15,165,166,1666,133,11,111]);
    dump(PHP_VERSION);
    dump(is_object($user));
    dump(is_array($user));
    dump(count($user));
    dd($user);
```

output:

```
"7.2.19"
true
false
9
Collection {#825 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▶]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be the most useful for collections

`if(count($user->toArray()) > 0)`

perhaps a better way (untested)

`count(($user ?? []))`

Answer (score 1):

The `count` method isn't supported when the data returned can differ from array or object. An alternative would be to use a `where` statement that always returns an array when called:

```
$users = App\User::whereIn('id', [12,13,14,15,165,166,1666,133,11,111])->get();
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: You can clearly see isobject returns true. also the example yoi gave is not the problem, its the single result.which is giving me trouble.

Comment: After some research, it seems you are correct and what i am expecting is not normal laravel Model behaviour, apologies for the down vote, please edit your answer so i can un vote

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to count a `$user` when you are only finding it by id? Of course it will only return either 1 or 0.